# dilemma of using "createHashHistory" vs "createBrowserHistory" incontext of deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

i am using "[gulp-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect)" as a development server and i am trying to implement react router 1.0.0-rc1.

Currently i am using "createHashHistory" which adds junk something like: ?_k=ckuvup in the URL, which is deliberate as defined in the [document](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url). I am ok with it until i am sending query strings along with URL and my link looks something like this with the junk appending just after the domain name rather then at the end:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=y754gg/jobs?latitude=27.686784000000003&longitude=85.2690875&query_location=Liverpool, United Kingdom&query=fjdkf
```

Expected URL (something like this) :

```
http://localhost:8080/#/jobs?latitude=27.686784000000003&longitude=85.2690875&query_location=Liverpool, United Kingdom&query=fjdkf/?_k=y754gg
```

I could have used "createBrowserHistory" which has a much clear URL but the problem is:
1) Server configuration. Example provided only shows how to do in [Express](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server). I am planning to use nginx in production and am using gulp-connect in development. As i could not find any reference on how to do in this servers i had to choose "createBrowserHistory".

2) My backend is on rails and if i through my front end in "public" folder, URL with # should separate client and server routes. But i keep on thinking there must be a way to use createBrowserHistory with some configuration in nginx.

My priority from this question is the first part on appending the key at the end. Any reference on how configuration are done in different server will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to disable the URL hash by setting `queryKey: false` when creating your history:

```
var history = History.createHashHistory({
  queryKey: false
});
```